# Binding StringFormat and Converter together

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-7, data-binding, windows-phone-8

I take user's avatar url from the web service (`User.Avatar`):

```
 /users/user_id/12?last_update=timestamp
```

In different controls I must use different size avatar (a web service can crop and resize image) :

```
 ImageSource="{Binding User.Avatar, StringFormat=http://myurl.com/\{0\}/crop/110x110, Converter={StaticResource ImageSizeUrlConverter}}"/>
```

Converter must take

http://myurl.com/users/user_id/12?last_update=timestamp/crop/110x110 (with `StringFormat`)

and return

```
http://myurl.com/users/user_id/12/crop/110x110?last_update=timestamp
```

But converter take `/users/user_id/12?last_update=timestamp` (without `StringFormat`).

This is normal behavior?

Comment: Please explain your problem more clearly.

Comment: sorry Sheridan, I trying to do the impossible, please check Toni Petrina answer's

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, it is supposed to be this way. You can bind any value to a string dependency property. Converter is used to convert from *that* type to *target* type. And since string formatting works only on strings, it makes no sense to act before the converter, only afterwords.

Here is an example:

```
{Binding SomeBoolValue,
         StringFormat=You said \{0\},
         Converter={StaticResource BoolToString}}
```

Where `BoolToString` returns "Yes" for `true` and "No for `false`.
Formatting *must* take place after you convert the source type to the target type.

You can send the data as the `ConverterParameter`, but that cannot be bound to a static property. Your best solution would be to create an attached property here that does the binding and conversion.